# Nunit.core and Nunit.util missing from v3

Tags: nunit

I have started upgrading to Nunit V3.2 however i cannot find nunit.core or nunit.util.

Just what is the upgrade path for these dlls from Nunit 2.6.2

Answer (score 5):

The nunit.core and nunit.util assemblies are not part of NUnit 3. NUnit 3 is an entirely new implementation of NUnit and while it closely matches NUnit V2 in it's Attributes and Assertions, it has a different internal design.

If you are a normal user, then you should not be using those two assemblies anyway. They are internal to NUnit V2. Your upgrade path is to convert your tests to V3, fixing any of the breaking changes noted in the docs. The "Upgrading" page at https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Upgrading gives a pretty good indication of the steps to follow.

If you are not a normal user - for example if you have your own runner that makes use of pieces of NUnit - you will have to ask a more specific question.

Comment: Thank you charlie, yes we have our own runner within our application to run nunit tests